# Unwanted redirect seemingly without reason

Tags: wordpress, apache, ubuntu, redirect, server

so I had recently been messing around with creating domains and such I registered a few and I am having a problem where no matter what the situation, even if apache2 is plain turned off, it redirects to the other domain.

I had installed wordpress on this and I will be the first to admit I was pretty careless, I removed it without much checking and forethought and now it appears to have come back to bite me.

The problem:

When I go to www.example1.com it redirects me to my other domain of www.example2.com. HOWEVER, when I go to www.example3.com it works perfectly fine, same with www.example2.com, it is only when I go to www.example1.com that it always redirects to www.example2.com

This happens regardless of if Apache is running or not.

Furthermore I have reinstalled apache (purged) as well as purged the /var/www directory

I have also been through iptables to see if that is the issue and no dice, I have also checked the dns routing on my host to make sure that I didn't accidentally set up a redirect there and it points at my ip as it should be.

Any help or suggestions of what to do would be greatly appreciated! Thank  you

Comment: Is it possible you setup domain redirection at the registrar level? Are you sure the DNS is setup correctly? When you ping the domains do they all return the same IP address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appear's that due to the way wordpress caches its redirects in the browser cookies I was getting a ghost redirect and there was in fact nothing wrong with the server. Simply had to clear the browser cache

(edit: wrong term)